# how to create links between pages?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
public class Libro
    {
        public string Titolo { get; set; }
        public string Autore { get; set; }
        public string Editore { get; set; }
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        public int Pagine { get; set; }
        public decimal Prezzo { get; set; }
        public int Quantità { get; set; }



        public Libro BuildLibro(string input)
        {
            Libro result = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                var inputArray = input.Split('*');

                if (inputArray.Length >= 6)
                {
                    result = new Libro();

                    result.Titolo = inputArray[0];
                    result.Autore = inputArray[1];
                    result.Editore = inputArray[2];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[3]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[3], out int num);
                        result.ISBN= num;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[4]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[4], out int num);
                        result.Pagine = num;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[5]))
                    {
                        decimal.TryParse(inputArray[5], out decimal num);
                        result.Prezzo = num/100;

                    }
                   
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputArray[6]))
                    {
                        int.TryParse(inputArray[6], out int num);
                        result.Quantità = num;

                    }

                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

in the Index.cshtml

```
    <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Titolo
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Autore
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Editore
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Prezzo(€)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
            
                    @foreach (var line in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Titolo)
 <p> <a href="@Url.Action("About","Home", new { titoloId = line.Titolo })"> Visualizza la scheda </a></p>
                            </td>
            
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Autore)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Editore)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Prezzo)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
            
                </table>
             </body>
            </html>
```

I have created a model of a book based on a list of a file.txt in order to display a table with all the books available, their author, publisher and price, now, for each book, I should be able to open a descriptive sheet also containing ISBN , pages and quantities. From paragraph in the html below @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Titolo) I inserted a link to the About.cshtml, but I don't know what code to write inside and what to write in the controller too?

this is my controller at the moment:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var fileInput = Reader.Read("C:/Users/test/source/repos/Books/Books/App_Data/Libri.txt");

            var libriList = new List<Libro>();
            if (fileInput != null)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i < fileInput.Count; i++)
                {
                    var libri = new Libro();
                    libri = libri.BuildLibro(fileInput[i]);

                    if (libri != null)
                    {
                        libriList.Add(libri);
                    }
                }
            }
        Session["currentLibriList"] = libriList;
        return View(libriList);
    }

       public ActionResult About(string titoloId)
    {
        var myFilteredList = new List<Libro>();
        if (Session["currentLibriList"] != null)
        {
            var lookupList = (List<Libro>)(Session["currentLibriList"]);
            myFilteredList = (List<Libro>)lookupList.Where(x => x.Titolo == titoloId);
        }
        return View(myFilteredList);
    }
```

and this is About.cshtml

```
<html>
<body>

    <table class="table">
        @foreach (var line in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Titolo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Autore)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Editore)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Prezzo)<p>€</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Pagine)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.Quantità)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => line.ISBN)
            </td>

        </tr>
        }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Url.Action` helper to send the `line.Titolo` to your `Controller` method and get your data:

```
<td>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("About","Home", new { titoloId = line.Titolo })">@line.Titolo</a></p>
</td>
```

Your `Index` method will store the data in a `Session` variable and then you retrieve this `Session` in your `About` method and cast it to the `List<Libro>` type. Once you get the list, then you can filter it out based on the `titolId`. Your last step would be to send this filtered list to your `About` view. You need to build your `About` view as per your requirement with the filtered data.

```
public ActionResult About(string titoloId)
{
    var myFilteredList= new List<Libro>();
    //Get data for titoloId
    if (Session["currentLibriList"] != null)
    {
      var lookupList = (List<Libro>)(Session["currentLibriList"]);
      myFilteredList=lookupList.Where(x=>x.Titolo == titoloId);
    }
    return View(myFilteredList);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fileInput = Reader.Read("C:/Users/test/source/repos/Books/Books/App_Data/Libri.txt");

    var libriList = new List<Libro>();
    if (fileInput != null)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < fileInput.Count; i++)
        {
            var libri = new Libro();
            libri = libri.BuildLibro(fileInput[i]);

            if (libri != null)
            {
                libriList.Add(libri);
            }
        }
    }
    //Set your session here
    Session["currentLibriList"]=libriList;
    return View(libriList);
}
```

Comment: Well, now I have the link! But of course the page that opens (About.cshtml) from error 404 as empty! what can I write so that it displays the card of the single book?

Comment: @Ludema63 What do you mean? Once you get your `titoloId` in the About method, you can lookup your required data based on how you have stored in. In you case, you can store your data in a `Session` and then retrieve the required information from it. Also the 404 is coming because you need to build your `About` view in your project.

Comment: Another aspect would be to use `Ajax` which only show/update a portion of the page without reloading the entire page but that is little more complex.

Comment: let me explain: if you look at my ActionResult Index(), opening that view I see a table with ALL the titles, author, publishers etc .. of the list I have in the file("C://.... text), in actionResult About what code can I implement so that I only see the details of the book I clicked on?

Comment: @Ludema63 Check updated answer. It will give you a direction on where to go about this.

Comment: I changed all the code as it is at the moment, you can see it on....unfortunately " myFilteredList = (List<Libro>)lookupList.Where(x => x.Titolo == titoloId);" throws an unhandled exceptionSystem.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast objects of type 'WhereListIterator'1[Books.Models.Book]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Books.Models.Book]'.'

Comment: @Ludema63 Convert it to a list: `myFilteredList = (List<Libro>)lookupList.Where(x => x.Titolo == titoloId).ToList();`

Comment: the exception is ok, but the link does not generate anything, when I click it opens error 404... did you look at the status of my code on?

Comment: @Ludema63 What do you mean by that? Where is your `About` view placed? 404 means not found so you need to check if the engine is able to render the view correctly. It should be placed under `/Views/Home/About.cshtml`

Comment: sorry I still do not know how it all works, tell me if I voted positively